# corba Vs socket programing for IPC

Tags: operating-system, corba

Corba is used for inter-process communication in our company.

My doubt here is, how corba is advantageous over socket programming ?

On what basis we choose whether to use corba or socket programming ?

Comment: socket programming is very low level, you have to do a lot of things yourself. CORBA provides you a much higher abstraction level handling a lot of things you would have to program yourself. Of course, you can do everything yourself, but you have to ask yourself, is that your job, or just leave that to a middleware product like CORBA, just as you could create your own OS but you can also use one that is available on the market. CORBA does also have the advantage that it is an open standards based solution!

Comment: @Johnny Willemsen: can we use socket programming and Corba together ?

Comment: Sure you can do your own socket programming yourself. You can also re-implement the TCP/IP stack, or write your own NIC driver. These things have been commoditized and implemented already to prevent you from having to re-do it. CORBA can do it, but so can other middleware technologies.

Comment: Yes, you can use together without problems, just as you can use any other technology when using CORBA

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing vastly different technologies.

CORBA provides (not an inclusive list):

- A standard endian-independent format for marshaling binary data
- Server location independence
- Thread pooling and dispatching
- Programming language independence
- Server lifetime management
- Synchronous or asynchronous remote procedure call like abstraction

Sockets are low-level tools for network communications. CORBA provides a massive infrastructure framework for distributed computing that is usually (but doesn't have to be) based on top of sockets.

> On what basis we choose whether to use corba or socket programming?

That depends on your requirements and many other factors too broad to answer here without any other details.